# Tesseract takes 10 seconds to recognize the simplest possible image, what did I do wrong?

Tags: image-processing, mingw, ocr, tesseract

I'm testing [this code](https://github.com/cppan/tesseract_example/blob/master/with_cmake/src/main.cpp) which is a basic example of tesseract.

As you can see: https://github.com/cppan/tesseract_example/blob/master/phototest.tif the image that comes with it is very very simple.

However my computer takes 10 seconds to recognize this image's text using this source code.

Both debug and release takes the same amount of time.

It's on a Windows VM with 4 cores, not the fastest machine but decent, can play youtube normally, etc.

**UPDATE:**

I compiled the same example on Linux and it takes like 0.3 seconds to recognize the same image.

Comment: Did you turn on optimizations?

Comment: @CrisLuengo https://github.com/bradosia/mingw-w64-x86_64-static-tesseract I'm using this static library compilation, don't know if he did. I'm gonna ask.